# Forward [only] unfiltered emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I am using a new email address, but I still want to get email from my old one. However, I do not want to get *all* the mail. A lot of my mail is filtered into different labels. I do not want to delete it, but I do not want these emails forwarded to my new address. I only want to forward new *unfiltered* mail.

I am pretty sure there is no way to this in vanilla Gmail. Any another ideas?

Answer (score -2):

I found a way that seems to work.

If all your other filters has "Skip the Inbox (Archive it)" selected, then "label:Inbox" will find the mails remaining in the Inbox.

"label:Inbox" goes in the "Includes the words" field in the filter creation dialog, and you have to click through a warning that this will never match anything, but my test just now worked just as intended.

I created this filter using "label:Inbox" in the regular search field, then clicking the dropdown and creating a filter form there. The search expression did not show up in the "Includes the words" until after the filter was saved. I guess this points to how you can create and refine arbitrarily complex searches and save them as filters.